# Does Optapy allow access to Optaplanner Benchmarker?

Tags: optapy

Is there a way to use the Optaplanner benchmarker using Optapy? If not, will this be added? What do you suggest to do in order to facilitate systematic benchmarking of Optapy solvers in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no OptaPy Benchmarker yet.
It will likely be added in the future as OptaPy grows, but there are more priority issues in OptaPy, such as full features support, more quickstarts and bringing the performance closer to OptaPlanner's performance.